# How can I get woocommerce $order_id in namespace and class

Tags: woocommerce, plugins, hook-woocommerce

```
<?php

namespace ecpay_logistics;
```

**This one is working.**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', __NAMESPACE__. '\checkout_review_order_custom_field_update',10,1);

function checkout_review_order_custom_field_update( $order_id ) {
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'my_split_checkbox', $_POST['my_split_checkbox'] );
  }
}
```

**I tried to merge in Class, but not working anymore, and also not sure where is problem, so I guess it can't match $order_id when processed.**

```
class SELECTABLE_LOGISTICS {
   public static function init(){
       add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', array( __CLASS__, 'checkout_review_order_custom_field_update',10,1));  
   }

   public static function checkout_review_order_custom_field_update( $order_id ) {
       update_post_meta( $order_id, 'my_split_checkbox', $_POST['my_split_checkbox'] );
   }

}

SELECTABLE_LOGISTICS::init();
```

**I will try anything if have any ideas helpful. thank your time.**

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', array( __CLASS__, 'checkout_review_order_custom_field_update',10,1));
```

In the above line, You're closing the array at the wrong position, `10, 1` is inside your array right now.

The correct code will be like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', array( __CLASS__, 'checkout_review_order_custom_field_update' ), 10, 1 );
```

Comment: made a very sad mistake, Now it's working smoothly, thank your remind